# Set variables for multiple input IDs derived from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, input

Directly below, the user clicks the link, which calls a PHP script and returns a JSON object, through which I parse and create INPUT fields each with their own ID, which was part of the JSON object:

```
 $(function()
 {
   $('.addNewLink').click(function(e)
   {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#addNewForm input, #addNewForm select').val('');
     $.post('api/size_types.php', function(data)
     {
       var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       $('.size_types').empty(); 
       var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
       {
         return '<div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon" >'+item.SIZE_TYPE+'</span>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control size_types"
                 id="'+item.SIZE_TYPE+'" value="'+item.DEFAULT_TEU+'" />
                 </div>';
        });
        $('.size_types').html(htmlToInsert);
      });
      $('#addNewModal').modal('show');
    });
  });
```

In the code above, I was able to loop through the JSON and create INPUT fields all with their own ID's using `item.SIZE_TYPE` and have the values set to `item.DEFAULT_TEU`.

On the HTML side, there is a form, but hopefully I don't have to show that code.  Just know there is a submit button with an ID called `#addNewSubmit`, which I will display the JavaScript directly below:

```
 $('#addNewSubmit').click(function()
 {
   var addservice = $('#addservice').val();  // user entered field
   // here is where I'm stuck
 });
```

What I need to do is create variables using the INPUT fields automatically created by the JSON object.  In my current case, 58 INPUT fields have been generated, all with their own ID and DEFAULT_VALUE.  The user has the option to change the DEFAULT_VALUE.

After searching the web, I found this code and added it to the click event directly above, right beneath the first variable:

```
 var size_types=new Array();
 var j=0;
 $(".size_types").each(function(){  // looking at the class, I need the ID
   size_types[j]=$(this).val();
   j++;
 });
```

Using this, I can return the values of each of the INPUT fields in an ALERT box, but I need the IDs so I can send them all to a PHP script to INSERT into a database.

How can I get each ID and its VALUE and set them all to their own variables? Or, is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could just send the `size_types` array from a hidden input field.